# Взять расписание с сайта

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Нужна взять расписание со страницы сайте https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/
Пытался использовать Jsoup

```
document = Jsoup.connect ("https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/").get();
System.out.println(document.title());
```

К сожалению, эффекта 0. Никаких сообщений об ошибке я не получаю, а title пуст
Далее, пробовал получить html страницы вот так:

```
public class UrlConnectHelper {
    private String content = null;
    public String getHtml(String url)
    {
        try {
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");
            content = scanner.next();
    }catch ( Exception ex ) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
        return content;
    }
}
```

Получаю бесполезный кусок html кода (не код самой страницы).

```
<html><head></head><body><script>var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();function eraseCookieFromAllPaths(name) { var pathBits = location.pathname.split("/");var pathCurrent = " path=";document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";for (var i = 0; i < pathBits.length; i++) {pathCurrent += ((pathCurrent.substr(-1) != "/") ? "/" : "") + pathBits[i];document.cookie = name + "=; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;" + pathCurrent + ";";}}eraseCookieFromAllPaths("BHC");xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() { if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) { var a=xmlhttp.responseText;document.cookie="BHC="+a+"; path=/";document.location.href="/esport/matches/"; } };xmlhttp.open("GET", "/banhammer/pid", true);xmlhttp.send();</script></body></html>
```

Мне кажется, проблема в том, что сайт использует защиту от DDoS и проксирование, но как это решить не знаю.

Comment: Вроде редирект на странице. А у сайта нет API?

Comment: Мне кажется что список как то из БД выводится и вы в `html` коде ничего не найдете

Comment: Смахивает на то что страница полностью формируется аяксом

Comment: API нет.
Надо как то преодолеть редирект. Загрузка страницы статична, никаких запросов на сервак со страницы нет, кроме загрузки картинок, js и css файлов.

Comment: @ASYOU, аяксом она не формируется. Откройте исходный код и посмотрите, игры выводятся прямо. Sanych Goilo, заголовки в запрос все передали?

Comment: @ASYOU нет никаких запросов. Я смотрел вкладку network в браузере, там бы это показало.

Comment: @ModaL никакие заголовки не передавал. Представил весь код, который использовал.

Comment: @Sanych Goilo, так передайте http-заголовки. Accept, User-Agent и так далее и сообщите, что будет.

Comment: @ModaL как их передать и какие параметры задавать?

Comment: @SanychGoilo  я проверил вторым методом все норм выводиться. Какую версию джавы вы используйте? Это выдало при первом же запросе на этот сайт?

Comment: @FORTRAN java 8. Да, при первом запросе

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно получить значение по ссылке https://dota2.ru/banhammer/pid и передать Cookie BHC=<значение> в запрос.

1. Запрос на https://dota2.ru/banhammer/pid с заголовком `Referer: https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/`
2. Получаем прямым текстом ответ от https://dota2.ru/banhammer/pid *(Пример: `3tYF8uhzelr3WAu6TqYikXIOTDg%3D_232290966385`)*
3. Подставляем это значение в виде Cookie BHC при запросе к https://dota2.ru/esport/matches/ *(Пример: `Cookie: BHC=3tYF8uhzelr3WAu6TqYikXIOTDg%3D_232290966385`)* и без проблем получаем содержимое страницы

На PHP я полностью получил необходимую страницу. Так как JAVA не знаю, код под него написать не смогу.

Comment: пример можно, пожалуйста? если перейти на http://dota2.ru/banhammer/pid выводит, что сайт не отправил данных

Comment: Я JAVA, к сожалению, не знаю. Но в PHP это можно сделать с помощью CURL (CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER). Вам нужно сделать запрос на https://dota2.ru/banhammer/pid и там вернётся значение BHC, которое нужно передать в http-заголовок Cookie. Пример: Cookie: BHC=pY9jnanaDDEQ6V7WGh%2FsJHscqVI%3D_228698677516

Comment: Куда оно вернется? Откуда мне его взять? На самой странице сайта такой куки нет. Возможно она удаляется, я не знаю.Извиняюсь за свою тупость.

Comment: @Sanych Goilo, оно возвращается прямым текстом на странице.

Comment: @Sanych Goilo, ничего не удаляется. Смотрите скриншот http://image.prntscr.com/image/f911b9389fdc4dd4aa554ce6c3c44e1f.png Полученное значение BHC передаётся при каждом запросе к сайту.

Comment: если перейти по ссылке https://dota2.ru/banhammer/pid там ничего нет!

Comment: @Sanych Goilo, я обновил свой ответ и расписал всё по пунктам. Посмотрите.